# Do I have to fake a value object in my unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, tdd

I have written a class using TDD containing a method (method under test) which takes a simple value object as a parameter (`range`).

**Code:**

The method under test looks like this:

```
public List<string> In(IRange range)
{
     var result = new List<string>();
     for (int i = range.From; i <= range.To; i++)
     {
          //...
     }
     return result;
}
```

Furthermore I have a unit test to verify my method under test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void In_SimpleNumbers_ReturnsNumbersAsList()
{
    var range = CreateRange(1, 2);
    var expected = new List<string>() { "1", "2" };
    var result = fizzbuzz.In(range);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, result);
}

private IRange CreateRange(int from, int to)
{
    return new Fakes.StubIRange() 
    { 
        FromGet = () => { return from; }, 
        ToGet = () => { return to; } 
    };
}
```

**Question:**

I have read Roy Osherove's book on unit testing ("The Art of Unit Testing"). In there he says

> "external dependencies (filesystem, time, memory etc.) should be
>   replaced by stubs"

What does he mean by *external* dependency? Is my value object (range) also an external dependency which should be faked? Should I fake all dependencies a class have?

Can someone give me an advice

Comment: It means that you should be testing the process under review and not the filesystem/time/memory. Don't rely on concrete implementations of dependencies because they can change. You are correct in Stubbing `IRange` since you are trying to test the method `In` with any `IRange` and not just one particular implementation.

Comment: How many implementations of IRange are there? Is this an interface you introduced purely to support mocking?

Comment: @Romoku if the implementations of IRange follow LSP then it shouldn't matter which implementation is used to feed the test, and using one concrete implementation would not invalidate the test.

Comment: Can't you replace that `IRange` interface with `IEnumerable<int>`? Your `In` method can be defined as `In(IEnumerable<int> range)` and you can call it with `fizzbuzz.In(Enumerable.Range(1, 2))`.

Comment: A lot of functional languages would allow you to treat this kind of record type as a tuple interchangeably. For example in Nemerle you could say `def (min, max) = SomeRange(0, 100);` Then the method signature would be `fizzbuzz.In(range : int * int)` allowing you to pass in any Range, or simply a tuple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

Do the simplest thing possible that solves your problem.

---

The longer I have been using TDD, the more I appreciate the value of being pragmatic. Writing super-duper isolated unit tests is not a value unto itself. The tests are there to help you write high quality code that is easy to understand and solves the right problem.

Adding an interface for the range class is a good idea if you have the need to be able to switch to another concrete range implementation without having to modify the code which depends on it.

However, if you do not have that need adding an interface serves no real purpose, but it does add some complexity, which actually takes you further from the goal of writing easy to understand code which solves the problem.

Be careful not to think to much about what might change in the future. [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) is a good principle to follow. If you have been doing TDD you won't have any problems refactoring the code if an actual need occurs in the future, since you have solid tests to rely on.

In general terms I would not consider a proper Value Object to be a dependency. If it is complex enough that you feel uncomfortable letting other code use it when under test it sounds like it is actually more like a service.

Answer (score 3):

A unit test should run in isolation (completely in memory) without having to touch any external systems, such as file system, database, web service, mail service, system clock, or anything that is either slow, hard to setup, or undeterministic (such as the ever changing system time).

To be able to do this, you should abstract away those external dependencies which allows you to mock them in your tests.

A unit test however, goes one step further. In a unit test you often only want to test the logic of a single method or a single class. You're not interested to verify how multiple components integrate, but you just want to verify that the logic of that single class is correct, and that it communicates correctly with other components.

To be able to do this, you need to fake those other components (the class's dependencies). So in general you should indeed fake all dependencies (that contain behavior) a class has.

Comment: +1 Agree in principle, but I think value objects should be treated differently. A value object (in DDD terms) would not need to be faked/mocked as it's simply a data container - it appears that this might be the case here.

Comment: @MattDavey: I agree. That's why I state in my answer 'that contain behavior' and 'in general'.

Comment: True, I'm not convinced the value object here should even be abstracted behind an interface. The tell-tale sign is that the mock is only setting up property getters - not behaviour.

Comment: @MattDavey: And the use of Microsoft Fakes even makes it worse. Did you see that ugly `FromGet = () => { return from; }` line? That's just insane.

Comment: @Steven: My value object doesn't have any logic that is the reason why I am asking this question. It feels weird to apply an interface to the Range class. Is there any rule/best practice which says you only fake an object when it contains logic ?

Comment: @MUG4N: Since that Range class contains only data and no logic, what would be the reason for you to fake it or add an abstraction over it?

Comment: @Steven: I thought it would be a good idea because of possible changes in the Range class und a higher robustness of my unit test

Comment: What change do you expect in that Range class where an interface actually helps? You will probably have to change the IRange interface as well when you change the Range class. And your unit test is currently not very robust. I would even say it is very unmaintainable at this point. As it is right now, that IRange interface is a useless abstraction. It doesn't help you. Since Range contains no logic, it never needs to be abstracted.

Comment: It's important to think about value objects as discrete values. Would you create an interface for `ints` or `doubles`? The same principle applies to value objects.